# ReactJS remember me component to hooks

Tags: reactjs

I have a case here, which is to make a remember me function when logging in.

So, yesterday I got an online repo on codesandbox which contains reactjs component remember me.

Then I want to convert it into react hooks.

The code is like this (React Component original)

```
import React from "react";

class RememberMe extends React.Component {
  static displayName = "RememberMe";

  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    isChecked: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (localStorage.checkbox && localStorage.email !== "") {
      this.setState({
        isChecked: true,
        email: localStorage.username,
        password: localStorage.password
      });
    }
  }

  onChangeValue = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  onChangeCheckbox = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      isChecked: event.target.checked
    });
  };

  loginSubmit = () => {
    const { email, password, isChecked } = this.state;
    if (isChecked && email !== "") {
      localStorage.username = email;
      localStorage.password = password;
      localStorage.checkbox = isChecked;
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { email, password, isChecked } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <table align="center">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Email</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  value={email}
                  onChange={this.onChangeValue}
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label>Password</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  value={password}
                  onChange={this.onChangeValue}
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colSpan="2">
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={isChecked}
                  name="lsRememberMe"
                  onChange={this.onChangeCheckbox}
                />
                <label>Remember me</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td colSpan="2">
                <input type="button" value="Login" onClick={this.loginSubmit} />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RememberMe;
```

**However, when it was finished, I tried to convert it into hooks, but it didn't work properly, I thought, "Is there something wrong in my code? Thank you**

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    
    const Me = () => {
      const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
      const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (localStorage.checkbox && localStorage.email !== "") {
          setEmail({ email: localStorage.username });
          setPassword({ password: localStorage.password });
          setIsChecked({
            isChecked: true
          });
        }
      }, []);
    
      const onChangeValue = (event) => {
        setIsChecked({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        });
      };
    
      const onChangeCheckbox = (event) => {
        setIsChecked({
          isChecked: event.target.checked
        });
      };
    
      const loginSubmit = () => {
        if (isChecked && email !== "") {
          localStorage.username = email;
          localStorage.password = password;
          localStorage.checkbox = isChecked;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <form>
            <table align="center">
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label>Email</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    name="email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={onChangeValue}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <label>Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input
                    type="password"
                    name="password"
                    value={password}
                    onChange={onChangeValue}
                  />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan="2">
                  <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    checked={isChecked}
                    name="lsRememberMe"
                    onChange={onChangeCheckbox}
                  />
                  <label>Remember me</label>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td colSpan="2">
                  <input type="button" value="Login" onClick={loginSubmit} />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    };

export default Me;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/remember-me-localstorage-forked-crpt1z

Comment: "it didn't work properly" isn't enough. What didn't it do that it should have, or what did it do it shouldn't have? Was there some error?

Comment: I've put the codesandbox link in my question https://codesandbox.io/s/remember-me-localstorage-forked-crpt1z
, can you try it? maybe you can fix it right there. I really appreciate it and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the types of your state.

Unlike with a class component where there's one `state` object with various keys, each state atom is now separate and should just hold the value itself, yet you're setting objects into them, e.g.

```
setEmail({ email: localStorage.username });
```

Invocations like that should be just

```
setEmail(localStorage.username);
```

and so on.

You also don't need `useEffect()`; just use [`useState`'s function initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Me() {
  // State, initial state loaded from local storage if set
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(() => (localStorage.checkbox ? localStorage.username : ""));
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(() => (localStorage.checkbox ? localStorage.password : ""));
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(() => !!localStorage.checkbox);

  const loginSubmit = () => {
    if (isChecked && email !== "") {
      localStorage.username = email;
      localStorage.password = password;
      localStorage.checkbox = isChecked ? "1" : "";
      alert("Okay!");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <table align="center">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Email</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="email" name="email" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <label>Password</label>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="password" name="password" value={password} onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="2">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isChecked}
                name="lsRememberMe"
                onChange={(e) => setIsChecked(e.target.checked)}
              />
              <label>Remember me</label>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colSpan="2">
              <input type="button" value="Login" onClick={loginSubmit} />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I've changed all three like this,
setEmail(localStorage.username);
      setPassword(localStorage.password);
      setIsChecked(true);
but the effect is the same, it's still an error. can you fix it in the codesandbox?

Comment: @AKX  Could you please help me with my question >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75454525/on-submit-system-blogdetails-getting-undefined-for-the-text-entered-in-the-mdedi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a number of things wrong with your hooks code. Let's go through a few of them in turn:

1. `if (localStorage.checkbox && localStorage.email !== "") {` 
   I notice that further down, you save the email like this `localStorage.username = email`. Why are you checking `localStorage.email`? Shouldn't you be checking `localStorage.username` in your if statement instead?
2. `setEmail({ email: localStorage.username });` 
   Try doing this instead: `setEmail(localStorage.username)`. You don't need the wrapping object here. Same thing goes for the other two fields.
3. This entire block doesn't make sense - why are you only using `setIsChecked` but expecting the other values to be updated? You'll need to create a different handler for each field accordingly.

```
const onChangeValue = (event) => {
  setIsChecked({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value
  });
};
```

4. `onChange={onChangeValue}` like point 3 above, you'll need `onChange={onChangeEmail}` and `onChange={onChangePassword}` as separate handlers.

Functionality aside, there's a number of additional things to consider:

- Accessibility. Read this page and consider changes accordingly: https://reactjs.org/docs/accessibility.html
- *DON'T* store passwords in plain text in localStorage. You should be passing them to a backend auth API and receiving either cookies or a JWT token.

If you make these changes you should get closer to a working project. Make sure you take the additional considerations into account before using your project anywhere in a real scenario!